# How can I see point in time rolling five week counts of distinct values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to see the point in time rolling five week count of distinct employees paid.  For example, in week 48 I would need to see the count of distinct employees paid in weeks 44 through 48.  I think I have to include something like "WHERE Week_Number BETWEEN Week_Number -5 AND Week_Number" but am not sure how to make this work.  The output should just be the Year, Week Number, and count of distinct employee IDs.

```
SELECT Week_Number,
    Year, 
Account, 
count(distinct EmployeeID as 'EmployeeCount'
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY Week_Number, Year, Account
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) Date functions are product specific.

Comment: Also, you will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Sorry, I'm obviously new at this.  What's the best way to provide the sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a data table like this:

```
YearNumber | WeekNumber | Account | EmployeeID
----------------------------------------------
2019       | 51         | 101     | 1         
2019       | 48         | 101     | 2
```

And this is the result you want to see:

```
YearNumber | WeekNumber | Account | Quantity
----------------------------------------------
2019       | 48         | 101     | 1         
2019       | 49         | 101     | 1 
2019       | 50         | 101     | 1 
2019       | 51         | 101     | 2 
2019       | 52         | 101     | 2 
2020       | 1          | 101     | 1 
2020       | 2          | 101     | 1 
2020       | 3          | 101     | 1
```

So one person starts paying on week 48, one at 51, which means their payment on account 101 overlaps on week 51 and 52, but on the other weeks, only one person pays to the account.

To also answer your question in the comment: this - I think - is a good way to provide a sample data and expected result when you ask on SO.

---

The query which helped me produce the results above:

```
SELECT 
    d.Year + IIF((d.Week + n.Number - 1) >= 52, 1, 0) AS Year, 
    (d.Week + n.Number - 1) % 52 + 1 AS Week,
    d.AccountID,
    COUNT(d.EmployeeID) AS Quantity
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM Number n WHERE Number BETWEEN 0 AND 4) n
GROUP BY
    d.Year + IIF((d.Week + n.Number - 1) >= 52, 1, 0),  -- Year
    (d.Week + n.Number - 1) % 52 + 1,  -- Week
    d.AccountID
```

This uses a [Number table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) which is basically a table containing the numbers - help a lot in queries like this. The code also has a minimal handling for year turning, but be aware that you may need to care for **years containing 53 weeks**.